# How to prompt user to enter both x and y coordinates in a single input in 2d array?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Hi i'm new to programming here. Currently doing an assignment to create a battleship game.
I have created a 2d array of random rows and columns.
However i'm stuck at coding the part where the user input is required to select the x and y coordinates.
I know that there is a way to individually ask for X and Y coordinates, for example :
"Enter rows: ", followed by "Enter columns: ". But I was wondering if there is a way for the user to enter both coordinates in 1 input, for example: "Enter X and Y, (eg. 5 6): "

Any help is much appreciated!

---

Comment: Yes, you need to [parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) the input. You could e.g. [`split()`](https://www.baeldung.com/string/split) the `String` at the `space` character and then parse both numbers as `int`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Any solution provide may not work for you since we don't know what follows the coordinate input.

Comment: @Mushroomator  Why not just call `nextInt()` twice.  It will move on to the next entry on the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this in Java. You can prompt the user to enter in a string and then split the string to an array of strings and then parse it as you need.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BattleshipGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter X and Y coordinates (e.g., 5 6): ");

        // Read the input as a single line
        String input = scanner.nextLine();

        // Split the input using a space as a separator
        String[] coordinates = input.split(" ");

        // Extract the X and Y coordinates from the array
        int x = Integer.parseInt(coordinates[0]);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(coordinates[1]);

        // Use the extracted coordinates in your game logic
        System.out.println("X coordinate: " + x);
        System.out.println("Y coordinate: " + y);

        // Close the scanner
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't close the scanner.  Assuming they will want more input it won't be possible to re-open it.  And what happens if only one value is entered on the line or if the values are separated by more than one whitespace character?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you type in two at at time you can just call `nextInt()` twice.  No need to mess with strings or parsing.  Type a negative number for `X` to stop input. It doesn't make sense to enter them in a `"2D"` array without knowing more about the array and how it is being used.  Once both values are entered, you can put them in a `"1D"`array using `int[] coords = {x,y};`

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Please enter next X and Y: ");
    int x = input.nextInt();
    if (x < 0) {
        break;
    }
    int y = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("X = " x + " Y = " + y);
}
```

Example output

```
Please enter next X and Y: 
10 20
X = 10 Y = 20
Please enter next X and Y: 
30 50
X = 30 Y = 50
Please enter next X and Y: 
-1
```

Considerations:

- make certain each X and Y value is within the proper range of the grid.
- make certain that you don't type more than two values at a time, otherwise you can get out of sync.